# How to force implicit invocation in Dialogflow (google actions)

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, implicit, google-home, invocation

I would like to know how to force dialogflow to use implicit invocation on my intents.

I have set up a custom domotic system (light, heating, coffee machine, etc..). 
it's controlled by a raspberry pi with webhook for dialogflow and it works fine. BUT I can't succed to call it implicitly.

For exemple, if i say :
"Ok google, i want to speak with assistant"
"Power on the light"
It works.

But if i just say :
"Ok google, power on the light"
It answer : "You havent set up this light"
(witch is the default responce of google assistant, not mine).

Does anyone know how to force it to use mine instead ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: So you want all of the implicit intents to go to your action? My guess is that while 'ok google, ask xyzzy turn on bed light' will work, you'll always need to invoke your action otherwise its Google's to parse. Unless I've mistaken your problem.

Comment: If i have an intents matching it, yes.
My goal is to remplace  'ok google, ask xyzzy turn on bed light' by 
 'ok google, turn on bed light'.

When i read here : https://developers.google.com/actions/discovery/implicit
it look like it's possible, but instruction with 'turn on/off' dont seem to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you've misunderstood the documentation at: [Implicit Invocation](https://developers.google.com/actions/discovery/implicit)

> The Google Assistant attempts to match the user's request to a suitable Action and then presents a few of these matched Actions to the user based on some qualitative and quantitative signals.

The point of having a 'good invocation phrase' is for Google to do matching (at their discretion) for those actions which match and present those to the user.

and the last line on that page reinforces that fact:

> These invocation phrases may not be unique to your Action; it's up to the Assistant to determine which Actions to suggest to users.

However if you are trying to integrate your Raspberry Pi based controller with Google Actions then you should look at [Smart Home](https://developers.google.com/actions/smarthome/): [Create a Smart Home Action](https://developers.google.com/actions/smarthome/create) You'll still need a cloud server to handle the interaction between Google and your hardware, but this way your end hardware is just another [light, fan, or camera](https://developers.google.com/actions/smarthome/guides/) as seen by Google.

Comment: Thanks ! that's what i was looking for.